# distinct value which has maximum id

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct, max

I am facing a problem in mysql query,i have 2 table.

1. `category_info`

   ```
   cid cname
   1   Latest News
   2   Notice Board
   3   Headline
   ```
2. `news_info`

   ```
   pid cid title               date
   1   1   mobile              2013-03-04
   2   1   fish                2013-03-04
   3   2   Airtel india        2013-03-04
   4   2   Marco Simoncelli    2013-03-05
   5   3   title1              2013-03-22
   6   1   title               2013-03-22
   7   3   International Opportunity   2013-03-22
   ```

I want to access title from table `news_info` distinct value which has maximum `pid`

I am using following query

```
SELECT a.*, b.*  FROM category_info AS a RIGHT JOIN news_info AS b ON (a.cid = b.cid)  GROUP BY a.cid
```

it give me distinct value but not max id. it give min id value.

Comment: Could you please post what output do you expect from the above example. Also any reason for why you are doing a right join?

Comment: Dear Rush,i expect output be

pid  title               date

6     title               2013-03-22
4    Marco Simoncelli    2013-03-05
7    International Opportunity   2013-03-22 thanks

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the answer to the question that you asked.  I'm not sure if it's what you actually want though.

```
select distinct title
from news_info
where pid = 
(select max(pid) from news_info)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

```
select ni.*
from news_info ni
order by pid desc
limit 1
```

In your example, there are no duplicate pids, so there is only one with the maximum value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another approach:

```
SELECT *
FROM news_info n
LEFT JOIN category_info c ON a.cid = b.cid
--
-- the maximum pid := there should not exist a higher pid value (for the same cid)
--
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT * FROM news_info x
   WHERE x.cid = n.cid
   AND x.pid > n.pid
    );
```